# variable does not exist for every trigger in my account

Tags: apex, trigger

Hi in my account every trigger throwing same error

> **Error: Compile Error: Variable does not exist: website at line 4 column 1**

Example:

```
trigger websiteass on Account (before insert) {
    for(Account acc:trigger.new) {
        acc.website='smak.com';
    }
}
```

Comment: I think website field is a custom one, here you have called the lable name,please use API Name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you have a class in your org with name as `Account`.

> Error Cause: When you access an Account or any SObject; compiler looks for a class first whether it exists then goes to assume its an `SObject`.

Try deleting the class and try again!

---

**Added**:

Trying to add an example on how it works or atleast how I think:

1. Works: Org has a Class with same name as any of Standard Object:

   - Class is not defined, hence compiler would assume its an SObject.

     ```
     Account objAccount = new Account();
     // following is legal
     objAccount.Name 
     // following is legal as SObject has all these properties
     objAccount.get('Name')
     ```
2. Doesn't Work: Org doesn't has a Class with same name as any of Standard Object:

   - Class is defined, hence compiler would assume you are trying to access a wrapper class.

     ```
     // Class with name as an Account
     public class Account {

         public class name;

         // constructor
         public Account() {

         }
         // methods
         public void add() { }
     }

     // example starts
     Account objAccount = new Account();
     // following is legal as there is a property defined in wrapper class
     objAccount.Name 
     // illeagal: no such method defined
     objAccount.get('Name')
     ```

**Workaround**:

- In worst/edge case scenario, if you still want to have a class with same name as any standard Object, like for instance while deserializing a JSON in Rest service; use wrappers as inner class as mentioned below:

  ```
  public class MainClass {

      // wrapper class
      public class Account {

      }
  }
  ```

---

Better alternative is to use Schema Prefix for accessing standard Object:

```
trigger websiteass on Account (before insert) {
    for(Schema.Account acc: trigger.new) {
        acc.website = 'smak.com';
    }
}
```

Comment: @khaleelmohammed, Don't forget to mark this as solved !!

Comment: Hi @khaleelmohammed, I had already added the cause, highlighted it now. Let us know if you have any additional questions.

Comment: @khaleelmohammed If this answer [addressed your problem](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) by clicking on the check mark/tick to the left of the answer, turning it green. This marks the question as resolved to your satisfaction, and awards [reputation](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) both to you and the person who answered. If you have >= 15 reputation points, you may also upvote the answer if you wish. There is no obligation to do either.